# Is sscanf compatible with dynamically allocated strings?

Tags: c, arrays, string, memory-management

I have written a program that reads data from a dynamically allocated string in a formatted way into a structure of 2 strings and 1 int. However, upon replacing the static char array structure fields with char pointers, the program ceases to work and ends with a timeout. Is it impossible to use sscanf() with a dynamically allocated array? Is there any easy way to adapt my program to dynamically allocated strings?

Comment: Yes, sscanf is "compatible" with dynamically allocated strings. Now show actual code we can help you debug.

Comment: It doesn't matter how you allocated the data, as long as you allocated enough room to hold the input. Including room for the null terminator. So your problem is not caused by the presence of dynamic allocation.

Comment: _"upon replacing the static char array structure fields with char pointers..."_: I guess those pointers don't point where they should. You should show us at least the relevant lines before and after your changes, then maybe we can help more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are trying to do it like this

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
  char *a;
  char *b;
  int c;
} s_fruit;

int main(void) {
  char str[] = "Apple Orange 2KG each.";
  s_fruit s;
  sscanf(str, "%s %s %i", s.a, s.b, &s.c);
  printf("%s\n%s\n%i", s.a, s.b, s.c);
  return 0;
}
```

so you get an error, because none of the pointers point to an allocated memory, so you can allocate memory to those pointers or just do it like this for example array of 10 chars including null terminator.

```
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct {
  char a[10];
  char b[10];
  int c;
} s_fruit;

int main(void) {
  char str[] = "Apple Orange 2KG each.";
  s_fruit s;
  sscanf(str, "%s %s %i", s.a, s.b, &s.c);
  printf("%s\n%s\n%i", s.a, s.b, s.c);
  return 0;
}
```

**Output**

```
Apple
Orange
2
```

**Note:**
This was just a simulation I don't know what you have written but I just guessed that you may have did something similar, happy coding!

Comment: Thank you! It turns out that the problem was actually something trivial - I forgot that after switching from tables to pointers, I also have to allocate memory for them, which I previously only did for my temporary text array. Thanks for the aid regardless!